# Printing a list of IF conditions

Tags: prolog

I have a number of Prolog conditions like this:

```
if has(X,Y)
     then need(X,Z).
```

Is there any way in which I could write a command to list all of these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code sample isn't valid prolog. Please state more clearly what you have and what you want!

Comment: try typing `listing(need).` at your Prolog prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not even close to valid prolog syntax. Here is a [great website](http://staff.um.edu.mt/mros1/prologcc/) you can use to learn the basics of Prolog.

There are many other resources available online which you can find by a Google search (free ebooks, sample codes, etc). Also, there's a book called *Programming in Prolog* by *William F. Clocksin* which I strongly recommend.

Comment: Being new to prolog and working off of examples, I was unaware that my question featured invalid syntax. Thank you for a constructive answer - I will look into both of your suggestions.

Comment: Check this one out as well, you might find the answer to your question on it: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what the original questioner meant ?

```
has(student, ambiguousquestion).

need(student, studymore).
need(student, doresearch).
need(student, reprasequestion).
need(student, helpustohelpyou).

?- has(X,Y), findall(Z, need(X,Z), Res), write(Res).
[studymore,doresearch,reprasequestion,helpustohelpyou]
X = student,
Y = ambiguousquestion,
Res = [studymore, doresearch, reprasequestion, helpustohelpyou].
```